# Get total turnover from current year --- not from last 365 days

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I would like to output the total turnover of all orders only from the current year.
The current year should be dynamically. It's important that the year will be updated automatically.

In the moment I can only output the turnover from the last 365 days.

```
let year = await Order.aggregate([
    {$match : {"createdAt":{"$gt":new Date(Date.now() - 24*60*60*365 * 1000)}}},
    
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '',
        "totalYear": { $sum:  '$getCartTotalPrice' }
      }
    }
  ]).exec();

console.log(year)
```

**Document example:**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId()
  products: Array
  getCartTotalPrice: 100
  owner: ObjectId()
  createdAt: 2020-10-21T14:24:17.918+00:00
  updatedAt: 2020-10-21T14:24:17.918+00:00
  __v: 0
}
```

**Expected output:** Sum of 'getCartTotalPrice' from all documents from current year (2021 e.g.)

Comment: Can you share an input example an expected output? Also, I think you need [`$year`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/) to group by the year.

Comment: I updated the question, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 {$match : {"createdAt":{"$gt":new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),0,1,0,59,59,999).toJSON()    }}}
```

Here is output from the js function:

```
 mongos> new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),0,1,0,59,59,999).toJSON()
 2020-12-31T23:59:59.999Z
 mongos>
```

Comment: I got an empty array. But If I remove .toJSON() it works. Many thanks!